# CentOS routing table has double entries for the default Gateway

Tags: linux-networking

I couldn't ping google so I took a look at my routing table:

```
# ip r
default via 10.30.0.1 dev eno2  proto static  metric 100 
default via 10.30.0.1 dev eno1  proto static  metric 101 
10.30.0.0/24 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.30.0.21  metric 100 
10.30.0.1 dev eno2  proto static  scope link  metric 100 
192.168.30.0/24 dev eno2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.30.3  metric 100
```

The entries about 10.30.0.1 via eno2 don't make sense because eno2 has IP/mask 192.168.30.3/24 and indeed if I delete these two all goes well:

```
# ip route delete default via 10.30.0.1 dev eno2
# ip route delete 10.30.0.1 dev eno2
# ping www.google.gr

PING www.google.gr (216.58.210.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from fra16s07-in-f3.1e100.net (216.58.210.3): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=132 ms
...
```

I don't see anything obviously wrong in my setup:

**Output of** `cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1`

```
NAME=eno1
DEVICE=eno1
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=10.30.0.21
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
ONBOOT=yes
UUID=...
IPV6...
...
```

**Output of** `cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno2`

```
NAME=eno2
DEVICE=eno2
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=static
IPADDR=192.168.30.3
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
DEFROUTE=yes
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
ONBOOT=yes
UUID=...
IPV6...
...
```

Comment: Hmmm... reading about DEFROUTE, PEERROUTES and it seems they are the root of my troubles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should remove `DEFROUTE=yes` from the configuration of eno2.

You also don't need the `PEERDNS=yes` and `PEERROUTES=yes` if you don't use DHCP to get the DNS and Default Gateway.

---

**References**

From https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/Deployment_Guide-en-US/s1-networkscripts-interfaces.html:

> DEFROUTE:  **yes** — Set this interface as the default route. **no** —
>   Do not set this interface as the default route.

From https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37670_01/E41138/html/ol_about_netconf.html

> PEERDNS: Whether the /etc/resolv.conf file used for DNS resolution
>   contains information obtained from the DHCP server.
>
> PEERROUTES: Whether the information for the routing table entry that
>   defines the default gateway for the interface is obtained from the
>   DHCP server.

Answer (score 1):

You should be having "DEFROUTE=yes" only in one of the interface files , the one through which you want to have the internet traffic to flow by default.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. I found out about it a few minutes earlier (and added my answer only a minute before yours)